# What is Tax Return document and where to search for it ONLINE?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, irs, business

I am wondering whether so called "Tax Return" document for X time period has any alternative definition or form code (form id number)? If yes, what is it? I am trying to find it online for wanted Inc company (USA) but cannot manage to find it anywhere. Already did a research on keyword "business search  name" but anything i found is physical envelope request only while i clearly defined that i would need this document to be downloaded online or in worst case faxed to me.

Comment: Are you trying to find the right document to file taxes for your own business?

Answer (score 2):

Tax returns are not public information. You can't see the tax returns of another person or corporation without their permission, and they can't see yours without your permission. ([source](https://prudentialassociates.com/who-has-access-to-your-tax-records/))

If you can get the other party to sign a [Form 4506-T](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-4506-t) then the IRS will provide you with a transcript of their tax return.